# Help understanding Web Service Callout Reponse

Tags: apex, api, class

I just created a web service using wsdl2apex, I am getting the response but I don't know if this response is right, what I mean is if already parsed, if so how can I get the values (VendorId, VendorName, VendorNo) and store them in a List so I can display them in a table.

Please don't put this question in hold, I made my research and I am so new in this field, it  is the first time I am doing this. therefore I am asking for help. Thank you in advance!

here is the apex code:

```
 public class MWSFISContr2 {

    Public String response {get;set;}
    public String debugSoql {
    get { return response; }
    set;
    }

    Public List<String> List1{get;set;}

    public class GetVendorDetails_element {
     private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://warehouseupdate.domain.com/','true','false'};
     private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{};
    }

    public String endpoint_x = 'http://warehouseupdate.domain.com/Service.asmx';
    private String[] ns_map_type_info = new String[]{'http://warehouseupdate.domain.com/Service.asmx', 'warehouseupdateDomainComServiceAsmx'};

    //button
    public void CreatePlan(){

        warehouseupdateDomainComServiceAsmx.GetVendorDetails_element request_x = new warehouseupdateDomainComServiceAsmx.GetVendorDetails_element();
        warehouseupdateDomainComServiceAsmx.GetVendorDetailsResponse_element response_x;
        Map<String, warehouseupdateDomainComServiceAsmx.GetVendorDetailsResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, warehouseupdateDomainComServiceAsmx.GetVendorDetailsResponse_element>();
        response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
        WebServiceCallout.invoke(
          this,
          request_x,
          response_map_x,
          new String[]{endpoint_x,
          'http://warehouseupdate.Domain.com/GetVendorDetails',
          'http://warehouseupdate.Domain.com/',
          'GetVendorDetails',
          'http://warehouseupdate.Domain.com/',
          'GetVendorDetailsResponse',
          'warehouseupdateDomainComServiceAsmx.GetVendorDetailsResponse_element'}
        );
        response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
        response = String.valueof(response_x.GetVendorDetailsResult);

        List1= new List<String>();
        List1.add(response);                        
        System.debug(List1.);     
   }
```

}

Here is the response:

> ArrayOfVendor:[Vendor=(Vendor:[VendorId=3117,
>   VendorId_type_info=(VendorId, http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema,
>   string, 0, 1, false), VendorName=Bratt Decor,
>   VendorName_type_info=(VendorName, http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema,
>   string, 0, 1, false), VendorNo=1001, VendorNo_type_info=(VendorNo,
>   http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema, string, 0, 1, false),
>   apex_schema_type_info=(http://warehouseupdate.domain.com/, true,
>   false), field_order_type_info=(VendorName, VendorNo, VendorId)],
>   Vendor:[VendorId=3118, VendorId_type_info=(VendorId,
>   http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema, string, 0, 1, false),
>   VendorName=Levels of Discovery, VendorName_type_info=(VendorName,
>   http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema, string, 0, 1, false), VendorNo=1002,
>   VendorNo_type_info=(VendorNo, http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema,
>   string, 0, 1, false),
>   apex_schema_type_info=(http://warehouseupdate.domain.com/, true,
>   false), field_order_type_info=(VendorName, VendorNo, VendorId)]

this is the response of the webservice:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetVendorDetailsResponse xmlns="http://warehouseupdate.domain.com/">
      <GetVendorDetailsResult>
        <Vendor>
          <VendorName>string</VendorName>
          <VendorNo>string</VendorNo>
          <VendorId>string</VendorId>
        </Vendor>
        <Vendor>
          <VendorName>string</VendorName>
          <VendorNo>string</VendorNo>
          <VendorId>string</VendorId>
        </Vendor>
      </GetVendorDetailsResult>
    </GetVendorDetailsResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: I've got to confess i'm really trying to help you here, but still struggling to know what you mean by 'but I don't know if this response is right, what I mean is if already parsed'. In terms of 'already parsed', yes the platform will automatically parse the XML into the Apex classes generated by the WSDL2Apex feature. As regards 'if the response right', what makes you think its wrong? The main difference i see is 'string' values in the XML elements and what looks like sensible values in your Debug output, is this intentional in your question?

Comment: Andrew, thank you for trying to help me, I wasn't sure if the response was right because besides the values I requested, VendorId, VendorName and VendorNo. it is displaying 'VendorName_type_info+url'. Now I that you mentioned I don't have to worry about parsing it, which is great. But how can I get the values VendorId, VendorName and VendorNo in a list.

Comment: The VendorName_type_info etc are just static variables in the generated classes from the WSDL2Apex tool, i assume your output above was from Debug log? To get the actual output in Apex code you need to assign the generated Web Service method response to a variable, which can be stored in a controller member variable and thus bound to from Visualforce. If you can include your Apex code so far that would be helpful.

Comment: the output above is a string response = response_x.GetVendorDetailsResult

Comment: Andrew, I added the apex code in the question. As you see I was able to add the response inside a List<String>, but I just want to display the VendorId, VendorName, VendorNo so I can display the in a table

Comment: You need to keep going dereferencing the contents of response_x.GetVendorDetailsResult, using the dot notation, take a look at the definition of the GetVendorDetailsResult member of the warehouseupdateDomainComServiceAsmx.GetVendorDetailsResponse_element class

Comment: I've got to signoff for the night now, but if your still struggling by the time i check back in, post a Github Gist of the full source code the generated Apex code for your web service and I can give you a full example, i cannot really give you an exact answer without seeing that.

Comment: Ok i fix it, I made an instance of the class generated by wsdl2apex:  public List<warehouseupdateDomainComServiceAsmx.Vendor> Vendors{ get; set; }  in the button:  warehouseupdateDomainComServiceAsmx.ServiceSoap request_x = new warehouseupdateDomainComServiceAsmx.ServiceSoap(); //Create the service
        warehouseupdateDomainComServiceAsmx.ArrayOfVendor vendorDetails = request_x.GetVendorDetails();  //Make the call
        Vendors = vendorDetails.Vendor;

Comment: Andrew, now I need to be able to update Salesforce records from .Net. I was making some research about this topic but It seems to be many ways, would you give me an advice about this? Thank you in advance!